# Can SQLite automatically roll back?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I developed an app that has been in use by a small company for over a year.
The tablet got brought to me (for some maintenance work) and I can't find my app on the home screen.

I also noticed the tablet is on safe mode. I restarted the tablet and every thing now seems okay.
Then I found that all the data entered over the last six weeks into my app and saved in the database is gone.
The database seemed to rollback to six weeks ago.
Other than that, the app is behaving normally.

How do I find/fix the issue? I seem to have lost six weeks of data.

For what it's worth, the tablet is a Lenovo Yoga and the android version is 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB cannot do this; old data gets overwritten.

This looks as if the tablet's storage is broken. (And because of the flash wear levelling, it's likely that not all of your data is in the state as of six weeks ago.)

Comment: Is there a way to confirm the damage on the storage? I very much appreciate your answer. I see the downvotes on the question and I'm surprised. Folks probably think I don't know what I'm talking about. I'm not new to programming and I know very certainly that different tables in the database lost data... and these are tables for which NO DELETE/UPDATE STATEMENTS exist in my code.

Comment: [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) does not guarantee anything; you'd have to compare against a known-good backup.